# Restricting the number of list items?

Tags: php, list

What I'm aiming for is a limit on the number of list items on one page, and then for them to be transfered onto a new page. I want to do this so I can add new list items quickly and without worrying if the page is too long/takes too long to load. A point in the right direction would be great, and an example of the code I need would be better! Thank you

Comment: How do you add the list items? From database? Hardcoded html?

Comment: HTML, presumably I need to start adding them from a database?

Comment: Well, you could of course just make multiple html files, store those html with the extra list elements (say, 10 elements each) on the server and load them via ajax, if you are comfortable with jquery or other js library it is not such a big job. Or, why not just load a few elements to begin with plus a link "See more..." or similar to load a second page with all the elements?

Comment: Hadn't thought of the "See more..." link, thanks :D
I am pretty comfortable with jQuery but not so much Ajax. Reckon I could integrate the "See more..." button with jquery/javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general technique is called paging. See, for example, http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/paging-using-php.aspx

The idea is to use a `LIMIT` clause in your SQL database query to retrieve a subset of results, specified by an offset within the list of records and the number of records starting at that offset to retrieve. You then modify `gallery.php` to accept a `page` GET parameter (as the tutorial that I linked to does; i.e. `gallery.php?page=3`) or an `offset` GET parameter (i.e. `gallery.php?offset=36`) and modify the `LIMIT` clause appropriately. For example, if you have 12 items to a page, then page 2 of the gallery displays records 12 through 23 inclusive (counting from zero).

**EDIT:** Here is example PHP code:

```
<ul class="ulgallery">
<?php

$gallery_items = array(
    array("img_src" => "image1.png", "title" => "This is image 1.", "author" => "John Doe"),
    array("img_src" => "image2.png", "title" => "This is image 2.", "author" => "John Doe"),
    array("img_src" => "image3.png", "title" => "This is image 3.", "author" => "John Doe"),
    array("img_src" => "image4.png", "title" => "This is image 4.", "author" => "John Doe"),
    array("img_src" => "image5.png", "title" => "This is image 5.", "author" => "John Doe"),
    array("img_src" => "image6.png", "title" => "This is image 6.", "author" => "John Doe"),
    array("img_src" => "image7.png", "title" => "This is image 7.", "author" => "John Doe"),
    array("img_src" => "image8.png", "title" => "This is image 8.", "author" => "John Doe"),
    array("img_src" => "image9.png", "title" => "This is image 9.", "author" => "John Doe"),
    array("img_src" => "image10.png", "title" => "This is image 10.", "author" => "John Doe"),
    array("img_src" => "image11.png", "title" => "This is image 11.", "author" => "John Doe"),
    array("img_src" => "image12.png", "title" => "This is image 12.", "author" => "John Doe"),
    array("img_src" => "image13.png", "title" => "This is image 13.", "author" => "John Doe"),
    // ...
    array("img_src" => "image304.png", "title" => "This is image 304.", "author" => "John Doe")
);

define("ITEMS_PER_PAGE", 12);

$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? (int)$_GET["page"] : 0;
if ($page < 0)
    $page = 0;

$num_pages = (int)((count($gallery_items) + ITEMS_PER_PAGE - 1) / ITEMS_PER_PAGE);
if ($page > $num_pages)
    $page = $num_pages;

$end_index = ($page + 1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
if ($end_index > count($gallery_items))
    $end_index = count($gallery_items);
for ($offset = $page * ITEMS_PER_PAGE; $offset < $end_index; ++$offset) {
    $current_gallery_item = $gallery_items[$offset];
    // output the <img> tag for $gallery_items[$offset];
    echo '<li><a href="#"><img src="' . $current_gallery_item["img_src"] . '" /></a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

I haven't tested it, but it is along the lines of what I am suggesting.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've been looking at the tutorial and I'm a bit fuzzy starting off. First of all, I'm currently adding the list items by html, as I'm not all too familiar with sql database. Do I need a better knowledge of SQL before I start doing this? thanks

Comment: @Jake: The `LIMIT` technique assumes an SQL database, but you don't need an SQL database to perform a similar technique. If you have an array of gallery items in your PHP script, then you can page within that. So, for example, if this array is called `$gallery_items`, then you can only output the HTML for 12 of the items at a time based on the `page` GET parameter.

Comment: @Jake: I added some sample PHP code to my answer.

Comment: Looks great, thanks so much! Do I still need the list for the image? How should I output it?

Comment: @Jake: The `ul` element seems to be working well for you. You don't need to get rid of it. See my updated answer. The exact HTML that you output depends on the information within `$gallery_items`, but I added `echo '<li><a href="#"><img src="' . $current_gallery_item["img_src"] . '" /></a></li>';` to give an example of "how to output the <img> tag".

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I've been messing about with the code for a bit and trying to figure out how it works. One thing I'm going to add is a link at the bottom which links to the next page. Would I be correct in saying I could use the echo function and a few variables?

Comment: @Jake: Yes, absolutely. Knowing that `$page` runs from 0 to `$num_pages` (inclusive), then if `$page` is greater than 0, you add a "previous page" link to `'gallery.php?page=' . ($page - 1)`. If it's less than `$num_pages`, then you add a "next page" link to `'gallery.php?page=' . ($page + 1)`.

Comment: @Jake: You're welcome. I am glad that I could help.

Comment: Just out of interest, where did you learn all of this stuff? University? College?

Comment: @Jake: I began learning PHP eleven years ago at a computer programming course at Stanford University. Since then, I have had a lot of practice. Practice and reading programming books is the best way to learn how to program.